# How to list all the files matching criteria and select first file using shell script?

Tags: regex, shell

I am trying to write one shell script which will

1. List all the files matching some criteria like 'files having .txt extension' and then
2. Choose first file from that list

I have managed to list all the files having .txt extension using `ls *.txt` command saved it in variable. My shell script looks like following

```
#!/bin/bash

all_text_files=`ls *.txt`
echo $all_text_files
```

On my system, I get following output

```
sample_text_file_1.txt sample_text_file_2.txt sample_text_file_3.txt sample_text_file_4.txt sample_text_file_53.txt
```

As you can see, all the files are separated by single space. Now I want to select first file i.e. `sample_text_file_1.txt` file and then read that file.

As I am totally new to shell script programming, I do not know how to do this in shell script. In other programming languages we can just split the string using regex on single space character and then choose first item from resulting list.

Request you to please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Using a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) array using no pipes and only `bash` built-in :

```
array=( *.txt )
echo "${arrray[0]}"
```

---

Using `printf` and `head` (no file-names with newlines allowed, but it's quite rare)

```
printf -- '%s\n' *.txt | head -n 1
```

---

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
printf -- '%s\n' *.txt | sed -n '1p'
```

Comment: -1, your `printf` answer is not robust as it does not handle filenames containing newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `head` to take the first output line:

```
ls *.txt | head -n 1
```

However you shouldn't use `ls` and parse its output unless you have specific reasons to do that (e.g. you want to sort files by some criterion and take the first one).

Comment: @sputnick, agree. Using ls makes sense if "first" is defined in terms of `ls` (sorted by time, size, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the output of ls is [not safe](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), so don't do it.

Store the files in an array and pick the first element like this:

```
arr=( *.txt )
echo "${arr[0]}"
```

Comment: Exactly what I said before

Comment: You hadn't said it when I checked your answer. Clearly you updated it.

Comment: It doesn't show up in the revision history if you edit it within 5 minutes. I'm not a newbie.

Comment: Next time refresh your browser before saying wrong assumptions

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you anymore. I see that you have edited your answer and put my solution at the top of it. I have also flagged your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Awk has `split` functions, which is quite POWERFUL.

```
awk 'BEGIN{split ("file1 file2 file3", files, " "); print files[1]}'
```